# jquery not work when function innerHTML called

Tags: jquery

i want to make *add more* function with `innerHTML` but i just realized that my jquery not work when i called *add more* function. This is my code:

```
<div id="col">
<button class="confirm" style="width: 146px;margin-top:6px;">
    <i class="pr10 mr5" style="border-right: 1px solid #fff"></i>
    Buy
</button>
</div>
<div id="a"></div>
<a onclick="javascript:a()">a</a>
<script>
function a(){
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML += '<div class="col"><button class="confirm"     style="width: 146px;margin-top:6px;"><i class="pr10 mr5" style="border-right: 1px solid  #fff"></i>Buy</button></div>'; 
}
$(".confirm").click(function ()
{
alert("a");    
})
</script>
```

the jquery just work on first button. Anyone know my mistakes?thanks.

Comment: Don't mix javascript and jQuery. You already using jQuery, so use jQuery in `a` function too: `$("#a").html("your html");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page is created, your button is not yet existed so all the events will not be available for this element, in this case you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to attach those events such as click in your case to this newly added button:

```
$('#a').on('click',".confirm",function () {
    alert("a");    
})
```

Another side note is to use `.click()` event handler instead of inline `onClick` event since you're using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a click handler for an element that is loaded dynamically you should  set the event handler on a parent object (your anchor that is not loaded dynamically)  and give it a selector that matches your dynamic object like the code here:

```
$('#a').on("click", ".confirm", function() {});
```